# Node red crash after a few minutes from start

Tags: node-red

When i start **node-red**, after few second it crashes and I've got this error:

```
 - [red] Uncaught Exception 

 - Error: write after end
```

what can i do for fix it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information, like where and how are you running node-red, what version, is it a clean install, have you installed any nodes, have you created any flows.

Comment: Uncaught exceptions tend to mean you have a badly behaving node. We need to know what nodes you are using. As it stands this question is unanswerable

Comment: thank you very much, I solved practically I had a fairly high number of s7 nodes that connected to some plc but it was not working and all the "ennconect" error messages made node red go inside that exception